# Treat delimiters as input tokens

Tags: java, c++, parsing, delimiter, parentheses

I'd like to know how to do this in both C++ and Java (EDIT: I don't mean simultaneously.  I'm asking two similar questions, "How do I do this in C++?" and "How do I do this in Java?").

I want to parse input from a file and treat '(' and ')' as delimiters in addition to whitespace.  But I also want each encounter of '(' or ')' to be recognized as an individual token. So for example when parsing

> This contians (nested (parentheses))

I would like successive calls to next() (or >>) to give (one per line)

```
This
contains
(
nested
(
parentheses
)
)
<end of input>
```

Are there parsers/scanners with this functionality built-in?  I know Java's Scanner is powerful, but as far as I can tell there's no way to determine *which* delimiter was matched each time you encounter the next token.

Comment: Would it be more appropriate to split this into two questions? One for C++ and one for Java?

Comment: You might want to read about [compiler compilers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiler-compiler). For example, [ANTLR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANTLR) is able to create parser code both for Java and C (which of course can be used in C++).

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean simultaneously.  I'm trying to cram two similar questions into one: "How do I do this in C++?" and "How do I do this in Java?" I'll clarify that

Comment: If this were python, the correct tool is shlex.  It does exactly this

Answer (score 1):

[Compiler-compiler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiler-compiler) discussion aside, this kind of parser can be naively implemented using two indices, something like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < str.size(); ) {
  int j = i;
  for(; j < str.size(); ++j) {
    // check for spaces
    if(str[j] == ' ') {
      // capture substring index i to j-1 as a token
      i = j+1;
      break;
    }

    // check for brackets
    if(str[j] == '(' || str[j] == ')') {
      // str[j] is a token
      i = j+1;
      break;
    }

  }

  // no more characters to check
  if(j >= str.size()) break;
}
```

Basically i is a marker to indicate start of a token, and j is used to search where the token ends.

Disclaimer: code above is not tested, might contain syntax error and bug especially with empty input, blanks etc, and likely to perform poorly over large data. Please consider using 3rd party library before reinventing the wheel.

Or for solution with minimal amount of code, you can just replace every occurrence of "(" with " ( " (likewise with ")") and do a white space tokenisation:

```
str.replaceAll("(", " ( ").split("\s+");
```

Comment: Yes, my question was asking about existence of such a device in STL, but I would happily accept a 3rd party library which does the same.  I can't find one for either C++ or Java which is strange because it seems to me like a fairly typical-use case.

Comment: The replaceAll option doesn't work if I'm pulling data from a stream rather than a string.  I want something that can be done in a single pass (I could of course pull words individually and then put back the delimiter and everything following or else maintain a queue of the to-be-read tokens which have already been split, but both these options still seem like large nasty hacks to solve what should be a very simple problem)

Comment: Your code fails to capture a string token followed immediately by a open/close-paren (w/ no whitespace).  It skips straight to the paren.  So for my example, your code would return "This", "contains", "(", "nested", "(", ")", ")" and misses the word "parentheses".  Would you mind fixing it to handle that case?  It seems to me like you would need some sort of put-back method or you need to track the current size or something.

Comment: @dspyz I quickly wrote the code with the intention of giving you underlying idea, not the ultimate solution. So as a 'motivated' programmer I believe you should be able to fix it yourself

Comment: I recognize that, but the fix illustrates the major problem with your code which is that it assumes I'm listing results rather than creating an iterator.  C++ does not have a 'yield' keyword, so this is not really a solution to my problem.

Answer (score 0):

This should be easily handled by a regular expression.
Something along the lines of `"\\s*(?:(\\w+)|([()]))" should do
the trick in C++11 (for earlier versions of C++, you'd need
Boost regular expressions).  Java also has regular expression
support, so you should be able to do the same there.

In both cases, the above expression skips white space, then
"captures" a symbol in group 1, or the parentheses in group 2.

Comment: What do I do with the regular expression?  Does C++ have some sort of scanner that matches instances?

Comment: @dspyz Regular expressions are part of both Java and modern C++.  If you have an up to date compiler, with C++11, you can just use `std::regex` and `std::regex_search`; otherwise, you'll need Boost regular expressions (and replace `std::` with `boost::`).  In Java, it's in `java.util.regex`.

Comment: I looked up std::regex and std::regex_search.  This solution suffers from the same problem as the other.  It operates on strings, not streams.  I'm looking for an iterator built on top of stream or a stream method.  The point is to read these tokens in from a file or stdin one-by-one, not to create a list of elements from an existing string.

Comment: @dspyz `std::regex` doesn't require a string.  It requires a bidirectional iterator, however, which excludes streams.  In practice, this will be the case for practically any tokenizer, because it has to be able to copy from the start of a token to the end, once it has found the end.  My own RE class will work with input iterators, but it doesn't do capture, and it's not really useful with an input iterator unless you design a special iterator, which keeps a copy of what it has seen.  Globally, it's usually preferable to read chunks of the input into a string.